# sharepoint 2010 hide admin pages

Tags: permissions, security

I have several lists on a public facing sharepoint site that are open to the public.  These are simple lookup lists and this configuration can't change (not my call).

Since users have access to the lists, they can get to the allitems.aspx page, the master page gallery, etc.  How can I prevent people from seeing the admin pages or a page to edit a list when they have access to them?

Also, the reason the access is open is due to performance when they elevated permissions when editing.  They went through a lot and won't change.  I really just need to get rid of the admin pages.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you cant set permissions on this lists, you can just leave contribution permissions for all users without possibility for lists management.
But if you don't want to do that, you can set redirect for pages you need to hide, user will come to page and will be redirected back. It is possible by developing simple web part in visual studio and placing it on page. Another way will not forbid access to the pages, but will hide content. SharePoint has audiences, it is groups of peoples calculated by some rules, you can build audience or use just SharePoint group. Each SharePoint web part has audience property, if it was set this web part will be shown only for that audience. For your example, you have allitems.aspx page, it is just page with xsltlistview webpart, you can open this page for editing and set audience.